# Extract cases from one table to another in Teradata

Tags: teradata

I don't know exactly how to formulate my question. This is my try:

I would like to extract or move or transfer data from one table to another.

I have a table lets say `db.temp`.

What I would like to have at the end is the following:

```
Create table db.temp2 as (select * from db.temp where DT < 'someDate')
with data primary index(something);

Delete from db.temp where where DT < 'someDate';
```

**Now to my question**:
I ***do not*** want to make a copy of the data I want to move to `temp2`, 
and then delete them from the `temp` table, 
but rather 'extract' them (i.e. do this in 'one step' so as to avoid taking up space).

*Something along these lines*:

```
extract * from db.temp where  DT < 'someDate'
to db.temp2;
```

Comment: You could do this with volatile tables and re-seed both `DB.TEMP` and `DB.TEMP2` to minimize the perm space, but you would have to be able to retain all of the data in spool space. In essence, you would create new copies of each table, purge the target tables, and reload them with the appropriate data based on your example.

Comment: Thanks for this, actually i do get spool space when i create a volatile table.